# Consultar hora de entrada y salida de empleado turno nocturno en sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

Recurro a ustedes en busca de apoyo y sugerencias. Tengo la siguiente tabla en SQL:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Es el registro de entradas y salidas de empleados que guarda un reloj checador, como verán no es posible diferenciar entradas de salidas ya que todo se inserta como columna. No tengo problema con obtener la hora de entrada y salida de aquellos empleados que NO tienen asignado un turno nocturno, ya que estoy usando un select min y max en el campo hora y agrupando por fecha e ID del empleado. Donde tengo problema es con aquellos empleados que tienen asignado turno nocturno :/ ya que no sé como seleccionar su hora de entrada y salida ya que registra entrada un día (15-12-2017 22:00) y sale al día siguiente (16-12-2017 6:00), inclusive es posible que por error cheque dos veces ya sea entrada y salida, en este caso ocupo de todas formas se visualice hora min y max. Alguna suegerencia de lo que pueda hacer al respecto? Lo que ocupo es obtener una salida así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La consulta que estoy usando actualmente es:

```
SELECT MIN(Hora) as HoraEntrada,MAX(Hora)AS HoraSalida,Fecha,IDEmpleado, IdTurno, TurnoNocturno FROM RegistroEmpleados GROUP BY IDEmpleado,Fecha,IdTurno,TurnoNocturno
```

Pero obtengo esta salida:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradecería muchisimo su ayuda.

Saludos!

Comment: Podrías mostrar cual es la consulta que tienes así, como en nombre de las tablas en cuestión?

Comment: Claro que si, la consulta que actualmente tengo es: SELECT MIN(Hora) as HoraEntrada,MAX(Hora)AS HoraSalida,Fecha,IDEmpleado, IdTurno, TurnoNocturno FROM RegistroEmpleados GROUP BY IDEmpleado,Fecha,IdTurno,TurnoNocturno

Comment: Para confirmar, ¿estás usando SQL Server? Toma en cuenta que decir `SQL` solamente no nos indica cual base de datos usas, `SQL` es simplemente el lenguaje para escribir consultas.

Comment: Si, estoy usando SQL Server 2008 R2

Comment: ¿Cuales son los tipos de las columnas `Fecha` y `Hora`?

Comment: @Jonsin si alguna de las respuestas ayudó a solucionar el problema de tu pregunta, por favor considera [aceptarla](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) haciendo click en el **✔️**, que está bajo las flechas de votación, a la izquierda de la respuesta  (no se te descuenta nada por eso -todo lo contrario, ambos se benefician).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo que pudieras hacer es establecer una regla que, cuando se trata de un turno nocturno, entonces si la hora de salida es menor a mediodía, entonces la fecha se agrupa con el día anterior.

Asumiendo que las columnas `Fecha` y `Hora` son de tipo `DateTime`, la consulta pudiera ser algo así:

```
SELECT MIN(Hora) as HoraEntrada,
       MAX(Hora)AS HoraSalida,
       CASE WHEN TurnoNocturno = 1 AND DATEPART(HOUR, Hora) < 12 THEN Fecha - 1 ELSE Fecha END AS Fecha,
       IDEmpleado, 
       IdTurno, 
       TurnoNocturno
  FROM RegistroEmpleados
 GROUP BY IDEmpleado,
          CASE WHEN TurnoNocturno = 1 AND DATEPART(HOUR, Hora) < 12 THEN Fecha - 1 ELSE Fecha END,
          IdTurno,
          TurnoNocturno
```

Obviamente, tu puedes ajustar la lógica a lo que quieres. Pero la idea es que tengas alguna lógica que te permita determinar cuando la fecha debe tomarse en cuenta como si fuera el día anterior.

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu ayuda Sstan. Me sirvió bastante tu respuesta. Mil gracias!

Comment: @Jonsin si esta respuesta te ayudó a resolver el problema, márcala como aceptada pulsando en el ✔ que encontrarás en la parte superior izquierda de la misma.