# Sumar o restar una columna en base al valor de otra y haciendo corte por ID

Tags: tsql, sql-server-2008-r2

Tengo una tabla llamada Registros con esta estructura:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que ocupo hacer es agregar a la derecha una nueva columna donde se vaya calculando un saldo (Ya sea sumar o restar) en base al valor que tiene cada registro en la columna Concepto; algo como esto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como pueden observar necesito que el cálculo se comience a hacer a partir del importe del primer registro de cada ID, es decir como si fuera haciendo un corte y en base a los registros posteriores se vaya haciendo el cálculo. Por ejemplo para cuando el concepto es 1 debe sumar y para 2 y 3 debe restar.

Tengo esta consulta pero me marca error en order y si se lo quito en la columna adicional saldo me pone la misma cantidad en todos los registros, es decir, ni suma ni resta :(

```
SELECT
    ID, Concepto, Fecha, Importe,
    SUM(Importe * case when Concepto = 1 then 1 else  -1 end) 
   OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Fecha ) AS Saldo
FROM Registros
ORDER BY ID, Fecha;
```

Comment: No se si una consulta logre esto.. un SP seguro...

Comment: ¿Tienes algún fragmento de código como sugerencia gbianchi?

Comment: yo no.. tendria que hacer un SP de 0.. el problema es que sql procesa los registros de a uno, a medida que vienen.. o en grupos con un group by.. vos queres comparar un registro con el anterior, ordenado de una determinada forma...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo sería necesario realizar:

```
SELECT 
    L.ID,
    L.CONCEPTO,
    L.FECHA,
    L.IMPORTE,    
    SUM(
        R.IMPORTE *
        CASE 
            WHEN R.CONCEPTO IN(2, 3) THEN -1 
            ELSE 1
        END
       ) [SALDO]
FROM REGISTRO L
LEFT JOIN REGISTRO R
    ON L.ID = R.ID AND L.FECHA >= R.FECHA
GROUP BY L.ID, L.CONCEPTO, L.FECHA, L.IMPORTE
ORDER BY L.ID, L.FECHA
```

[**DEMO**](http://rextester.com/IKZKY63885)

A lo comentado, habría un problema en el caso que no exista una columna que se considere como consecutivo. Para ello, podrías hacer:

```
;WITH REG_ENUMERADO AS(
    SELECT 
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY FECHA ASC) [INDICE],
        ID,
        CONCEPTO,
        FECHA,
        IMPORTE
    FROM REGISTROS
)
SELECT 
    L.ID,
    L.CONCEPTO,
    L.FECHA,
    L.IMPORTE,    
    SUM(
        R.IMPORTE *
        CASE 
            WHEN R.CONCEPTO IN(2, 3) THEN -1 
            ELSE 1
        END
       ) [SALDO]
FROM REG_ENUMERADO L
LEFT JOIN REG_ENUMERADO R
    ON L.ID = R.ID AND L.INDICE >= R.INDICE
GROUP BY L.ID, L.CONCEPTO, L.FECHA, L.IMPORTE
ORDER BY L.ID, L.FECHA
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu ayuda Davlio, ahora solo tengo un problema con la fecha ya que cuando los registros son de un mismo día, la columna de saldo muestra el total repetido debido al group by Fecha. Ya intenté quitar la fecha del group by y por defecto del select pero al hacer eso me da cantidades muy extrañas.Alguna sugerencia?

Comment: @Jonsin podrías [edit] tu pregunta e incluir ese caso. ¿La columna fecha no contiene horas? ¿No hay otra columna que se puede usar como consecutivo?, porque si solo tienes los días, entonces quizás podrías usar la anterior respuesta que propuse. Mira [Revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/revisions/133258/1)

Comment: Agradezco mucho tu respuesta @Davlio efectivamente no tengo un campo que me pueda servir de consecutivo más sin embargo utilicé el Row Number tal cual como me lo sugeriste, adecúe tu ejemplo a mi código y asunto arreglado. Ya obtuve justo lo que necesitaba.

Comment: @Jonsin no te olvides de dar como aceptada las respuesta que resolvieron tus preguntas. Aún queda pendiente que aceptes: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/127067/45